# OpenCV imread Acess Violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, opencv, directory

I am trying to import images from a folder using imread but it crashes from a access violation "Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->u was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEB."

The class doing this

```
#pragma once
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "ImageOut.h"
#include "dirent.h"
#include <fstream>

typedef struct TrainingData TrainingData;
bool isFileExtension(const char *file, const char *extension);
char *combined(const char *str1, const char *str2);

class TrainingManager
{
private:
    const char *path = "C:\\Users\\Cameron\\source\\repos\\JAVA_JNI_FTC\\Data\\";
    const char *pathData = "C:\\Users\\Cameron\\source\\repos\\JAVA_JNI_FTC\\Data";

    TrainingData *data;
public:
    void init_TrainingData(TrainingData *);
    TrainingManager();
    ~TrainingManager();

};

struct TrainingData
{
    cv::Mat * images;
    ImageInfo *info;
    int size;
};
```

The C++ file, The imread call at line 35 causes the error

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include "TrainingManager.h"

TrainingManager::TrainingManager()
{

}

void TrainingManager::init_TrainingData(TrainingData *data)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    std::ifstream file;
    if ((dir = opendir(this->pathData)) != NULL) 
    {
        int fileCount = 0;

        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) 
        {
            fileCount++;
        }
        fileCount -= 2;
        closedir(dir);
        data->images = (cv::Mat *) malloc(sizeof(cv::Mat) * fileCount/2);
        data->info = (ImageInfo *) malloc(sizeof(ImageInfo) * fileCount/2);
        dir = opendir(this->pathData);
        int infoIndex, imageIndex;
        infoIndex = imageIndex = 0;
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (isFileExtension(ent->d_name, "png"))
            {
                std::cout << combined(this->path, ent->d_name);
                std::string string = "C:\\Users\\Cameron\\source\\repos\\JAVA_JNI_FTC\\Data\\Data1.png";
                *(data->images + imageIndex) = NULL;
                cv::Mat *mat = new cv::Mat();
                imageIndex++;
            }
            else if (isFileExtension(ent->d_name, "txt"))
            {               
                file.open(combined(this->path, ent->d_name));
                int *info = (int *) data->info + infoIndex;
                int buf = 0;
                int index = 0;
                while (file >> buf || index < 4)
                {
                    *(info + index) = buf;
                    index++;
                }

            }

        }
    }
    else {

        perror("");

    }

}

bool isFileExtension(const char *file, const char *extension)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (*(file + index) != '\0') //go through the file until '.' indicating the start of the file extension
    {
        index++;
        if (*(file + index) == '.')
        {
            index++;
            int checkIndex = 0;
            while (true)
            {

                if (*(file + index + checkIndex) == *(extension + checkIndex)) //check the chars after the start of the period to check file extension
                {
                    if (*(extension + checkIndex) == '\0') return true; //if everything is equal up to
                    checkIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

char *combined(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    char *newString = (char *) malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) - 4);
    int index = 0;
    while (*(str1 + index) != '\0')
    {
        *(newString + index) = *(str1 + index);
        index++;
    }
    int last = index;
    index = 0;
    while (*(str2 + index) != '\0')
    {
        *(newString + index + last) = *(str2 + index);
        index++;
    }

    return newString;

}

int strlen(char *str)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (*(str + counter) = '\0')
    {
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I dont know if this a bug with open cv, my code or improperly defined dependencies but I have been looking around for a while and found nothing.

Comment: When a program crashes in visual studio it should offer the opportunity to debug the program. Take the offer and read through the stack trace (usually in the bottom right of the window) to see how the program met such an ill doom. Check out each call in the call stack and look at the variables involved to see where `this` got smashed. `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEB` looks like a null pointer was iterated backward. Buuuuut....

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `data->images = (cv::Mat *) malloc(sizeof(cv::Mat) * fileCount/2);` is valid? `malloc` is an old C function. It knows nothing about objects. It cannot call constructors because it doesn't know that constructors exist. If you `malloc` storage for a non-trivial object, the object's internal state is not initialized and the object is broken. Crom only knows what will happen if you try to use it.

Comment: The imread call at line 35 causes the error. I didn't see the imread. imread itself does not cause memory errors. Failed to find the file by path  will cause imread to return to NULL. The subsequent operation to null matrices is the cause of memory errors.  Can you post the relevant code about imread?